# Enable/disable a button until an item is selected in a listbox?

Tags: winforms, validation, button, listbox

How can i disable a button until an item is selected in a listbox?

Comment: What GUI framework are you using? Win32? GTK? Qt?

Comment: what sort of presentation technology are you using, ASP.NET, winform, WPF?

Comment: Sorry, but i'm using Win32 (Visual C#)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initially you disable your button:

```
button1.Enabled = false;
```

Then you subscribe to the SelectedIndexChanged event of the listbox. Bellow is the handler:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listBox1.SelectedIndex >= 0)
    {
        button1.Enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

You subscribe to the event from the Visual Studio IDE, or programatically like this:

```
listBox1.SelectedIndexChanged+=new EventHandler(listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention winforms, one way is to set the property of the button IsEnabled=false in the property explorer. Then add an event for the listbox OnSelectionChanged. VS will automatically insert the code behind for you, then you can put this in the event handler:

```
 button1.IsEnabled = listbox1.SelectedIndex > 0;
```

If you are using WPF you can do it the same way, but it would be better to use Databinding.

Comment: Sorry but don't have sufficient knowledge of C# to understand what you mean. Can you write down all the code I need for me?(IsEnabled doenst work)

Comment: There is no IsEnabled proeprty on the button class. Only 'Enabled'.